# What is the meaning of this "MuxOMX ctor" log in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, assets, android-studio

I'm developing a game in Java for Android using LibGDX with Android Studio. I'm using the AssetsManager class and I've noticed weird log when finishLoading() is finished:

```
10-17 22:15:17.108 31943-32282/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.146 31943-32285/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.182 31943-32291/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.231 31943-32296/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.284 31943-32299/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.330 31943-32302/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.385 31943-32309/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.425 31943-32312/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.462 31943-32315/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.499 31943-32318/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.546 31943-32321/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.607 31943-32324/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
10-17 22:15:17.654 31943-32327/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.698 31943-32330/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.740 31943-32334/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.782 31943-32339/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.822 31943-32343/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.864 31943-32346/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.911 31943-32353/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.953 31943-32356/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:17.997 31943-32359/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:18.043 31943-32362/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:18.087 31943-32365/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    10-17 22:15:18.139 31943-32368/com.gadarts.parashoot.android I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
...
```

Does anybody have any idea what it means? I've searched everywhere and couldn't find anything relevant.
It doesn't make any problem, it just blows my Android Monitor with these logs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find why it is happening? For me, it was not because of the asset manager. May be the pixmap images I'm loading.

Comment: Nope, haven't found anything yet (I'm not using pixmap). But AFAIK, Mux means multiplexer and the only multiplexer I'm using is for the touch handling. If I find anything relevant I'll reply back.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bit of errant logging code left in place by some library. A quick dig around the internet led me to [this reference source file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/70bdd112d885a0e9a3ff2d1d08b2dee990f1f568/media/libstagefright/OMXClient.cpp), for example, with a constructor implementation that simply does nothing but dumps that log message:

```
MuxOMX::MuxOMX(const sp<IOMX> &mediaServerOMX, const sp<IOMX> &mediaCodecOMX)
    : mMediaServerOMX(mediaServerOMX),
      mMediaCodecOMX(mediaCodecOMX) {
    ALOGI("MuxOMX ctor");
}
```

Further digging finds a bunch of similar threads about the issue, such as [this one from some IRC logs](https://echelog.com/logs/browse/libgdx/1489705200), that come to the same conclusion as above: this is a rogue log statement left in some Android library that is harmless, if annoying.

The [head version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/OMXClient.cpp) of that file doesn't contain the log statement. So it's possible you could alleviate this by upgrading your Android version.

It's also possible you can configure the log viewer to ignore "information" level levels, which would suppress this visually.